# Are date of birth forms necessary for alcoholic websites?

Tags: legal

I've noticed that many beer and spirits companies often require you to enter your date of birth before entering their site (ex. [Budweiser.com](http://budweiser.com/public/agecheck.aspx)).

Is this form legally required? Or is it just a popular convention?

If it isn't legally required/recommended, wouldn't it be a bad idea to funnel users through a form like this, just to see the content of your site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alcoholic beverage industry in the United States self-regulates its promotional efforts. Here's a PDF titled [Self-Regulation in the Alcohol Industry](http://www.ftc.gov/os/2008/06/080626alcoholreport.pdf) from the [Federal Trade Commission](http://www.ftc.gov):

> Underage alcohol use is a widespread
>   problem with significant health and
>   safety consequences. This is the third
>   Federal Trade Commission report on
>   efforts by the alcohol industry to
>   reduce the likelihood that alcohol
>   advertising will target youth, by its
>   placement or content. This report
>   provides data about how industry
>   members allocate promotional dollars;
>   data on compliance with the industry’s
>   advertising placement standard
>   (requiring that at least 70 percent of
>   the audience for advertising consist
>   of adults 21 and older); analysis of
>   external review of advertising
>   complaints; and an update on the FTC’s
>   “We Don’t Serve Teens” campaign. The
>   report is based on the responses to
>   Special Orders issued to twelve major
>   alcohol suppliers, comments submitted
>   in response to two Federal Register
>   notices, and discussions with a wide
>   range of stakeholders. It provides
>   alcohol supplier data in an aggregate
>   or anonymous fashion.

Basically, because of fallout from underage drinking, the industry makes an effort to place advertising only where 70% or more of the audience is adults 21 or older. Websites, as a promotional vehicle, need to assure that the audience for them is to an appropriate audience. They self-regulate as part of a long-term effort to assure that they are a responsible industry.

Comment: Your links appear to have been truncated.

Comment: That's weird. Fixed. Could not replicate the truncation in SO. Probably on my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any resources that stated that those forms are legally required.

Here's an article on the FTC website which talks about how alcohol companies have used this technique as a way to adhere to some industry guidelines.

http://www.ftc.gov/reports/alcohol/alcoholreport.shtm#bOnline%20Advertising